# DoctrineExtensions(Beberlei) does not work - Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-extensions

I installed the [Beberlei DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) but can't get the mysql DAY and YEAR to work.

I have this in my autoloader:

```
$doctrineExtensions = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', ROOT.DS.'library');
$doctrineExtensions->register();
```

And when i try to do following dql statement

```
   SELECT YEAR(e.eventdate) FROM \Entities\Event e
```

**I get following error:** Error: Expected known function, got 'YEAR'' in /usr/local/lib/php/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:42

In top of my file i have

```
use \DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql;
```

And i can see that it can find the class if i type:

```
    $test = \DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year::getSql();
```

But not if i type

```
    $test = Year::getSql();
```

Seems like some implementation is missing but can't find out what the problem is..

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader` as used in the other answers is now deprecated.

The proper way is something like:

```
use DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year;
...
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
// Can also be:
// $config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createConfiguration();
// Or:
// $config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([...]);
$config->addCustomDateTimeFunction('YEAR', Year::class);
```

You can also load from a configuration file using fully-qualified class names using `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration` `setCustomDateTimeFunctions([...])`, like so:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    dql:
      datetime_functions:
        year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
        month: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to register the function:

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions');
$classLoader->register();
...

$config = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration();
$config->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit late :) but it will help others like me that get from a client an old project.

You have to register the namespace of the DoctrineExtension directory:

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', APPPATH . 'libraries/vendor/beberlei');
$classLoader->register();
```

Now when you get the `DoctrineExtensions` from composer, it comes under the `src` directory, so just move up the content of the `src` directory (under the `DoctrineExtensions`) and add extension you need to the config :

```
$config->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
```